Grease pencil, selection problem
Newbie question. When i go to a layer in my animation  to draw -  two of them are selected  and I can only deselect by using 'none'  in object mode. Then I get no response to drawing/erasing  or selecting normally in those layers.  They are not locked  and are selected in layers.  I know I'm missing something simple and obvious and basic - but what is it?  Help greatly appreciated.

If I understand your question and your aim, the fastest way to deselect all strokes of a Layer is to lock it.
When a Layer is locked you will not be able to draw on it, nor edit its strokes.
You can also lock strokes by materials lock.
In object mode if you deselect one object you cannot edit it in any way.


Thank you, Josh  - now I think my problem relates to the tiny little dot which turns into a pencil icon.  Thanks for your help.
